# Unix sort command doesn't give me correct output

Tags: sorting, unix

I have input file (test) which looks like this:

```
MarkerName      Allele1 Allele2 Weight  Zscore  P-value Direction
rs8065651       t       c       2.00    -1.345  0.1787  --
rs12450876      a       g       2.00    -0.496  0.6201  +-
rs7209239       a       t       2.00    1.134   0.2569  ++
rs7210970       a       g       2.00    1.724   0.08462 ++
rs4791114       a       g       2.00    -1.156  0.2476  --
rs10853140      a       g       2.00    0.989   0.3229  ++
rs237316        a       g       2.00    0.738   0.4607  ++
rs11871508      a       g       2.00    -5.527  3.265e-08       --
```

I am running sorting command and trying to find the top 3 smallest values:

```
sort -nk 6 test | head -3 > output.txt
```

but it my result (output.txt) I am getting this:

```
MarkerName      Allele1 Allele2 Weight  Zscore  P-value Direction
rs7210970       a       g       2.00    1.724   0.08462 ++
rs8065651       t       c       2.00    -1.345  0.1787  --
```

This is obviously not good result.

Can you please help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to remove header line in the file.
`tail -n +2 test`

Then sort. For sorting floating values `-g` flag is used.
Also you need to be sure that your locale is correct. Otherwise collation rules will influence the result.
`LC_ALL=C sort -bg --key=6,6`

So:
`tail -n +2 test | LC_ALL=C sort -bg --key=6,6 | head -3`

Comment: Thank you so much!